# Dll library is not detected from the browser

Tags: asp.net, dll, reference

I am using a dll in my new web proyect, I added the dll as a reference but, when I call it from code behind it works fine, It detects the library in my visual studio

But when I runn it from a browser, it mark an error:
[enter link description here](http://fotos.subefotos.com/cb7e3854ef0a46790bb7fc0426f72802o.jpg)

PD: The dll works fine in my other 2 proyects(wpf & winform)

Does anybody knows what could it be?

Thanks!
And sorry for my english, im steal learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the file to "Copy to Output Directory"

Click the DLL in your solution explorer and it will be in the properties panel at the top

Comment: I did but still not working. Copy to Output Directory is: **Copy always**. Should I change BuildAction(content)?

Comment: Have you manually uploaded the dll to the website,

Also in IIS have you set the Application Compatability, select the app pool and then make sure you are using V4 not V2

Or vice versa

Comment: Yes, I added the dll manually and then I add it as a reference. Im using V4 Classic

Comment: Are you able to post the error translated to english via google translate please

Comment: Sure. Here is [http://fotos.subefotos.com/25f8c399b1086a11bc265cb84066454bo.jpg ] The google translator moved the text a litle

Comment: Cheers eduardo, 
Can you double check the namespace, open a new file and try to import and let intellisense do the import for you.

Sometimes webforms dont fully qualify the namespace

Comment: I created a new webform and call the library, but the same error appear. Im dead :'(

Comment: Thanks every body, the company decided to work on WPF, so I dont need to search the solution browser